# Can I implement iterator end() in ring?

Tags: c++, data-structures, iterator

First, I cannot really find much info about ring data structure on the Internet, so here's a short implementation showing what a ring is (according to my lecturer)

```
template<typename Key, typename Info>
class Ring
{
struct Node   // structure for storing the data
{
    Key k;
    Info inf;

    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
};

Node* any;  // pointer to a node belonging to the ring, NULL if the ring is empty
};
```

It's similar to a circular list, but `any` can point to any element in the structure, we don't care about the order, where we add, etc.

Besides my main task for the project, which I have already done, we have to implement iterator in such a way, that

```
for(auto it = r1.begin(); it != r1.end(); ++it)      // r1 is a ring
{ cout << *it << ' '; }
```

works properly, ie. prints whole ring.

Is it even possible? Iterator end() should point to a place, where the next element will be added, and we don't have such a point. If it's set to `any` (same as begin()), the loop will not be executed at all, and if it's set to `any->prev`, it will omit the last element.

Do you have any ideas, how can I implement this? Or am I right that it is impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`end()` is meaningless in the context of a ring: you can't identify a position in a ring that's "one past the last element", which is what `end()` is.

The idiomatic way of iterating over a ring is to send two iterators out in opposite directions from any point and terminate after both iterators have reached, and one of them has "processed", the same element.

Comment: Well, the phrasing "end() is meaningless" is still, uh, meaningless. `end()` is an end iterator, relative to `begin()`. For example, `end()` can simply be a default-constructed iterator.

Comment: We'll agree to disagree. Good weekend!

Answer (score 0):

For a one item ring, if both `begin()` and `end()` must refer to nodes, then `begin()` and `end()` clearly refer to the same node, but they can't compare equal because that would cause a loop to exit before the first iteration.

And so you can conclude that for these iterators equality can't be defined solely in terms of the nodes they refer to.

I.e. you just have to define iterator equality in a suitable way.

---

In many cases an end iterator is just a default-constructed iterator.

So this is nothing new.

---

Example:

```
#include <assert.h>         // assert.h
#include <iterator>         // std::(iterator, forward_iterator_tag)
#include <utility>          // std::(pair)

namespace cppx {
    class Non_copyable
    {
    private:
        Non_copyable( Non_copyable const& ) = delete;
        auto operator=( Non_copyable const& ) -> Non_copyable& = delete;
    public:
        auto operator=( Non_copyable&& ) {}
        Non_copyable() {}
        Non_copyable( Non_copyable&& ) {}
    };
}  // namespace cppx

namespace my {
    using std::pair;
    using std::iterator;
    using std::forward_iterator_tag;

    template< class Key, class Value >
    class Ring
        : public cppx::Non_copyable
    {
    public:
        using Pair = pair<Key, Value>;      // Movable

    private:
        struct Node             // For storing the data
        {
            // Key key;
            // Value value;
            Pair    kv;

            Node*   next;
            Node*   prev;
        };

        class Iterator
            : public iterator<forward_iterator_tag, Pair>
        {
        private:
            Node*   p_first_;
            Node*   p_current_;

            auto is_end() const -> bool { return p_first_ == nullptr; }

            void advance()
            {
                p_current_ = p_current_->next;
                if( p_current_ == p_first_ )
                {
                    p_first_ = nullptr;
                    assert( is_end() );
                }
            }

        public:
            friend
            auto operator==( Iterator const& a, Iterator const& b )
                -> bool
            { return !!a.p_first_ == !!b.p_first_ and a.p_current_ == b.p_current_; }

            friend
            auto operator!=( Iterator const& a, Iterator const& b )
                -> bool
            { return not( a == b ); }

            auto operator++()
                -> Iterator&
            {
                advance();
                return *this;
            }

            auto operator++( int )
                -> Iterator
            {
                Iterator result = *this; 
                advance();
                return result;
            }

            auto operator*() const
                -> Pair const&
            { return p_current_->kv; }

            auto operator->() const
                -> Pair const*
            { return &p_current_->kv; }

            Iterator( Node* p, bool be_end = false )
                : p_first_( be_end? nullptr : p )
                , p_current_( p )
            {}
        };

        Node*   p_current_;     // Node in the ring, 0 if the ring is empty.

    public:
        // TODO: add new node, before current node if any.
        void add( Pair kv );

        // TODO: advance n positions, backward for negative n.
        void advance( int const n = 1 );

        // TODO: a unique id for current position.
        auto current_position() const -> void const*;

        auto is_empty() const -> bool;

        auto current() const -> Pair const&;

        auto begin() const -> Iterator      { return {p_current_}; }
        auto end() const -> Iterator        { return {p_current_, true}; }

        Ring(): p_current_() {}

        Ring( Ring&& other )
            : p_current_( other.p_current_ )
        { other.p_current_ = nullptr; }
    };
}  // namespace my

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

auto operator<<( ostream& stream, my::Ring<int, int>::Pair const& kv )
    -> ostream&
{ return stream << "{" << kv.first << ", " << kv.second << "}"; }

auto main()
    -> int
{
    using Ring = my::Ring<int, int>;

    Ring r;
    for( int i : {3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 4} )
    {
        r.add( {i, i*i} );
    }

    // Output via explicit iteration.
    auto const first = r.current_position();
    do
    {
        if( r.current_position() != first ) { cout << ", "; }
        cout << r.current();
        r.advance();
    } while( r.current_position() != first );
    cout << "\n";

    // Output via range based `for` using `begin` and `end` iterators.
    int count = 0;
    for( Ring::Pair const& kv : r )
    {
        if( count++ > 0 ) { cout << ", "; }
        cout << kv;
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
{3, 9}, {1, 1}, {4, 16}, {1, 1}, {5, 25}, {9, 81}, {2, 4}, {6, 36}, {5, 25}, {4, 16}
{3, 9}, {1, 1}, {4, 16}, {1, 1}, {5, 25}, {9, 81}, {2, 4}, {6, 36}, {5, 25}, {4, 16}
```

Comment: In C++ Standard Library containers at least, `end()` never refers to an actual element, but one past the end.

Comment: @Bathsheba: *logically* one past the end. And "never refers to an actual element", I suspect that's incorrect for `std::valarray`, though I'm not sure. It's anyway not of importance.